# AngularJS routing - won't load view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I have been attempting to follow several different online tutorials, but keep keep failing on the same thing: getting AngularJS to load a HTML template file into the *ng-view* section in my page.

I have stripped it down as much as possible and am now essentially just copying [this simple tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-fuEtkasFs).

Please have a look at my test page here: http://inigowebdesign.co.uk/atest/ You should be able to see all the files there in the source code and confirm that they exist and are linked properly. Please, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is my code as it stands:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular JS Shizzle!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </header>       
    <div ng-view></div>
    <footer>
        <h3>Footer</h3>
    </footer>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider)){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'view.html'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/something'});  
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On your test-site I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` in the console log. I guess from this: `config(function($routeProvider)){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In console you have error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

This `)` was at the end of the first line.

Fixed:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'view.html'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/something'});  
});
```